# is it possible to use typescript and javscript together in a nativescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

i would like to know if i can use javascript and typescript in one project and how.
i have an existing nativescript core js project, i want to use a plugin, the [demo](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc/tree/master/demo/app/standard) is written in TS, and its a [webrtc plugin](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc/) so i don't understand it enough to start messing with the code

i have tried running `tns install typescript` before but it messed up my project.

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic considerations:

- When you use TypeScript, you have to know it is not a runtime language, is a compiled language.
- When you compile a TypeScript file, project or module, the TypeScript compiler (tsc) will generate the JavaScript files (usually CommonJS modules) according to the ECMAScript specification defined in the project (in TypeScript) config.ts file.
- If you need to use a plugin in JavaScript but it is programmed in TypeScript, you have to compile it first, and then import the module/s in you JavaScript project.

#### Advanced considerations:

- The ECMAScript specification version defined in the config.ts file, need to be compatible with your project JavaScript version.
- There is no way to integrate TypeScript in a JavaScript project using the same execution context, even if you use JavaScript with the ES6 specification. Remember, JavaScript is an interpreted language, not compiled.

---

#### Conclusions:

Consider to migrate your code to TypeScript, compile the plugin and add it manually or search an alternative for that plugin in JavaScript.

---

PD: Check [this](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-webrtc/issues/30) related issue in the `nativescript-webrtc` GitHub repository